Bluetooth headphones and losing connection
I have a pair of Sony WH-1000XM2 and have paired them with fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1
I installed blueman and then could find them and trust them however I could only find them when placing them right next to the laptop. As in hanging them from the screen.
I can switch them to an sound output device however only when hanged from the screen.
If I sit back in my chair I lose connection with them.
Any ideas what to do?
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
